# Iterating dataframe by unit of time instead of row by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that something looks like this:

```
Time(minutes)    column2       column1
420              1             5
420              2             10
420              3             8
421              1             4
421              2             9
421              3             7
```

I know how to iterate row by row using iterrows(), but is there an efficient way to iterate by unit of time in the column (Time) so that I can work with data for that given time in each iteration? Something like:

```
time = 420
while(time <= max_time):
   temp <- fetch the sub-dataframe for given time
   process(temp)
   update original df with temp #guaranteed it won't affect any other rows other than the current set of rows
   time += 1
```

Comment: What does `process(temp)` do in this case? It looks like you can start with `.groupby()`...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to iterate by time instead of by row like:

#### Code:

```
for grp in df.groupby('Time(minutes)'):
    ...
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    Time(minutes)    column2       column1
    420              1             5
    420              2             10
    420              3             8
    421              1             4
    421              2             9
    421              3             7"""), header=1)

print(df)
for grp in df.groupby('Time(minutes)'):
    print(grp)
```

#### Results:

```
   Time(minutes)  column2  column1
0            420        1        5
1            420        2       10
2            420        3        8
3            421        1        4
4            421        2        9
5            421        3        7

(420,    Time(minutes)  column2  column1
0            420        1        5
1            420        2       10
2            420        3        8)
(421,    Time(minutes)  column2  column1
3            421        1        4
4            421        2        9
5            421        3        7)
```

Comment: Is there an efficient way to update the old table (i.e replace the old group by new group?)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go. The first, which would basically keep your iteration format, would be to subset the dataframe manually:

```
for time in df['time_minutes'].unique():
    temp = df.loc[df['time_minutes'] == time] 
    process(temp)
    # or alternatively, make your changes directly on temp (depending what they are),
    # for example, something like this:
    # df.loc[df['time_minutes'] == time, 'some_column_name'] = assign_something_here
```

The other, and probably the more efficient way to go, would be to use a `groupby` as suggested above by [Stephen Rauch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48975108/6671176)